What is the word for a word that is used incorrectly in a sentence
Looking for a term for when a word is used incorrectly for whatever reason.
Example

Even thought at the moment

Correct

Even though at the moment

I’m sure this is a bad example. But I used it directly from something I just read.

The mistake may be typographical, rather than a 'use of English' error. I think the reason does matter. The general term is 'mistake'.

In your example, the mistake would be considered a typo. The general term for a usage error is solecism.

@Edwin Ashworth But the answers in that link are the wrong answers. Solecism is the correct answer.

@Zan700 I think you're right that the suggested link doesn't quite answer the question. But solecism doesn't appear to be right either. Barbarism, perhaps?

@Zan700 Plenty of other suggestions at Word for when one uses the wrong word in a sentence. Bottom line: covered exhaustively here before.

@Edwin Ashworth. At that link, I did find one answer that was solecism, and it received very little attention. But it was there! That link should be posted with the question. Thanks for responding.

@user405662 The user asks "Looking for a term for when a word is used incorrectly for whatever reason." That is the definition of solecism.

@Zan700 'Solecism' has the default sense in linguistics 'an offense against the rules of grammar by the use of words in a wrong construction'  [Ayres], which is not an exact match. 'He charged us an absorbent price' breaks no grammatical rule, but is clearly ludicrous. A misused word, not bad grammar.

@Edwin Ashworth From the second paragraph in that article: "In its broader implications," notes Maxwell Nurnberg, "a solecism is a deviation from the norm, something illogical, incongruous, absurd, or even an impropriety, a breach of etiquette" (I Always Look Up the Word Egregious, 1998).
The term solecism is derived from Soli, the name of an ancient Athenian colony where a dialect regarded as substandard was spoken.

@Zan700 But CD, Etymon, Collins and Wikipedia all list this as the first or only linguistic sense, signalling the most commonly used sense. 'Malapropism' is a closer fit to the title question, though one would guess the example OP gives to be a typo.

@Edwin Ashforth I've stated that thought/though is a typo (wandering finger). Malapropism fits your example of "absorbent price" (a confusion of words). If the good people of Soli stated or wrote either, the Athenians would have charged σολοισμός.
